# What controls horizontal space between levels of nested list?

Tags: html, css

Here are three shots of the same code illustrating what I mean. As you can see, they really vary.

[image: Nested list with WordPress 1.5 theme]
[image: Nested list with Subtlebeauty WordPress theme]
[image: Nested list with WordPress 1.6 theme]

And the code, for reference, is:

```
   <ul>
 <li>num 1</li>
  <ul>
   <li>num 1.1</li>
   <li>num 1.2</li>
   <ul>
    <li>3rd level</li>
   </ul>
  </ul>
 <li>num 2</li>
</ul>
```

I suppose this could be due to a variety of things, but it doesn't hurt to ask.
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON3Af.png):

Answer (score 2):

vertical space is generally controlled through CSS with `line-height`. For example,

```
li { line-height: 40px; }
```

You may find [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/howdoi/?p=151) useful, which lists some of the common CSS attributes used to style lists

**EDIT:**

In response to your edited question, you can control horiztonal spacing using `margin-left`. for example

```
<ul>
 <li>num 1
  <ul>
   <li>num 1.1</li>
   <li>num 1.2
    <ul>
     <li>3rd level</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>num 2</li>
</ul>
```

with CSS

```
li ul li {  margin-left:100px; }
```

will space lists of depth 1 or more 100px to the right. [Here's how that looks](http://jsbin.com/ugela)

Comment: Whoops whoops whoops. Terribly sorry. I meant horizontal. Thanks anyway. I'll edit the question. I get those mixed up, you know.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me your html is wrong, you cannot have an ul inside an ul. The correct syntax is:

```
<ul>
 <li>num 1
  <ul>
   <li>num 1.1</li>
   <li>num 1.2
    <ul>
     <li>3rd level</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>num 2</li>
</ul>
```

Notice that all the closing li's have moved to the end of that list item (including it's sub-items).

Using a css reset it should display the same way in all browsers (more or less...).

Answer (score 1):

I generally turn off an margin padding and line-height for `li`, `ul`, `ol` in CSS. I'm almost certain most browsers use margins to set this, but to be sure I set them all to 0.

```
ul, ol, li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to add the spacing.
You can use either top/bottom margin or padding. In your case I would choose margin:

```
li {
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 1em;
}
```

Also make sure you use a reset class to normalise the differences between browsers.